# Using --expose-gc for TypeScript with ts-node or tsx

Tags: node.js, typescript, ts-node, node-tsx

Neither `ts-node` nor `tsx` seem to support the `--expose-gc` flag, so the garbage collector object `global.gc` is always undefined. How am I supposed to clean up memory in my TypeScript code?

Answer (score 2):

### ts-node

Pull request [#536](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/pull/536) seems to have removed Node flags like `--expose-gc`, but it recommends that you do this instead:

```
node -r 'ts-node/register' --expose-gc file.ts
```

### tsx

The `--expose-gc` flag does seem to be supported by `tsx`:

```
tsx --expose-gc file.ts
```